# Is there any way to export raw data from Google Analytics using BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-api, google-bigquery

...without being a Google Premium customer?

There are a bunch of sources telling how I can export the raw data from GA to BigQuery if I'm a premium customer...

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference
http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/01/27/google-analytics-bigquery-whys-hows/

What I'm wondering is whether there is any way to do this without paying Google a hundred grand for the rights to my own logs.

> inb4 it's Google Analytics not Google Raw Data

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you can use solution from OWOX, it would be cheaper.
https://www.owox.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there really is no way to export raw, unaggregated, hit-level data from GA to BigQuery without being a GAP customer.

However, it is possible to leverage the GA API to capture the metrics and dimensions that you may be interested in and then upload these data as tables in BigQuery. The obvious downside being that it is aggregated data, and thus not at a user or interaction level.